# Capping part of a sum

Tags: finance, recursion

I have a financial constraint which states that:

`spend on x` cannot exceed 15% of `total spend`, where `spend on x` is part of the sum of `total spend`, ie:

```
`total spend` = `spend on x` + `spend on y` + ...
but 
`spend on x` <= 15% * `total spend`
```

Given the `total spend` and `spend on x`, how could I calculate `capped spend on x`?

Comment: if I understand meaning of *capped spend* correctly,(it being maximum amount you can spend on x), then it is nothing but $15 \% $ of *total spend*. What is the question then?? Please clarify the question..

Comment: This part of a social responsibility calculation. So businesses can spend more than 15% on x, but only up to 15% will be recognised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we start by calculating `spend_on_other`:

```
total_spend = spend_on_x + spend_other
```

therefore

```
 spend_on_other = total_spend - spend_on_x
```

Now we want to solve for `capped_spend_on_x` by assuming that `spend_on_x` is the maximum value (ie 15%), it follows that `spend_on_other` will be 85%. Since there is no cap on `spend_on_other` it follows that

```
capped_total_spend = capped_spend_on_x + spend_on_other
```

Given capped_total_spend is t,

```
t = 0.15t + spend_on_other
```

therefore

```
0.85t = spend_on_other
```

therefore

```
t = spend_on_other / 0.85
```

Having then the total capped_total_spend, we need only substitute

```
capped_spend_on_x = t * 0.15
```

therefore

```
capped_spend_on_x = (spend_on_other / 0.85) * 0.15
```

therefore

```
capped_spend_on_x = ((total_spend - spend_on_x) / 0.85) * 0.15
```